# Why do my Google Analytics URLs begin with slashes?

Tags: google-analytics

When looking at Google Analytics, all reports show URLs that begin with a slash and www: "/www.url.com/page.html."

I've never seen Google report like this. Webmaster Tools is set up correctly. Not sure what else can be set up in Analytics. Any idea?

Current: /www.url.com/page.html

Typical: /page.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

by default GA only reports the relative path and query string of the URL (it strips the protocol and domain.  So one of two things must be happening:

1) you have code that is passing a custom page name to the `_trackPageview` call, adding that "/[domain]".

2) you have a custom filter within the interface setup that is prefixing the page name with "/[domain]"

Adding the domain to the page name is a fairly common thing to do when you have GA code spanning multiple domains, most especially when they are going to a rollup profile, so that you can see which pages are coming from which domain.

So if I had to *guess* (and this is only a guess, seeing as how I don't have access to your 
code or GA interface), someone must have attempted to rebuild the full url to use as the page name instead of just the path+querystring - and then messed up (probably a messup in some regex with the protocol, if I wanted to throw even more guesses at it).

But the 64 thousand dollar question is.. where is it being changed? Like I said.. GA by default does not do this, so someone has added code to do it on your site, or else a filter within the interface.

I would start by looking to see if there are any filters in your interface, since that is the easier thing to determine. If you see no filters relevant to this, then you will have to look on your page code (including any script includes or other javascript code being output).  It would be a value passed with `_trackPageview` so `ctrl+f` for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it answers my question. Here's the code used:

_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'url.com']); 
_gaq.push(['_addIgnoredRef', 'url.com']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

Comment: @MichaelTerry well the code you listed there isn't doing it. Nor is it even prefixing the page name with the domain.  But the fact that you show the `_trackPageview` as not having an additional parameter tells me that it is almost certainly an improperly configured filter within the GA interface (alternative is maybe you have another `_trackPageview` somewhere else on the page that is doing it, in which case you have inflated page views to worry about, on top of this!)